# How to create a Observable from a Vert.x Future?

Tags: vert.x, rx-groovy

I have a instace of io.vertx.core.Future, because I need to set multiples handlers into the same Future, according this issue https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/issues/1920 the way to go is with Observables.

But I found no way to get a Observable from a Future.

I tried `rx.Observable.from( Future )` but it does not work because it is not a Java Future.

I look through `RxHelper` and there is no `toObservable` method that takes a Future as parameter.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `ObservableFuture` and use its handler as the handler of your original `Future`

```
import io.vertx.core.Future
import io.vertx.rx.java.RxHelper

def myFuture = Future.<String> future()

def obsFut = RxHelper.observableFuture()
myFuture.setHandler(obsFut.toHandler())

obsFut.subscribe({ s ->
  println "Hello $s"
})

myFuture.complete("John")
```

prints

```
Hello John
```